# How can i replace “/>XXXXX”/> with "/> in notepad++ where XXXXX are number

Tags: notepad++

I have a CSV file I am editing with Notepad++, and there is a section of about 500 consecutive lines where I want to replace `"/>XXXXX"/>` with `"/>` in notepad++ where `XXXXX` are number. Is there a way to do a Find/Replace All with Notepad++ on only that section?

Comment: is the number same all over the places

Comment: Karim, all those number are random 5 digit numbers

Comment: Can you provide an example input and output?

Comment: Ryan,input is "/>806408"/> "/>68522"/> and output is "/> "/>

Comment: Please always add clarifications by editing your question. When you would like to reply to a user use the following syntax @user3591858

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression search to specifically target the n-digit pattern.
Set the "Search Mode" to "Regular expression".
Set "Find what:" as

```
"/>[0-9]+"/>
```

and "Replace with:" as

```
"/> "/>
```

Edit- I fixed it for any length of number, at least one digit.

Comment: As you mentioned in another comment, "/>\d+"/> would work as well for the search term.

Answer (score 0):

Search for "/>*"/> ande replace with "/>

Comment: That may would break it. Let me rethink that. I think you're in need of some Regex

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Sed. it is not a perfect solution but might help you out

sed -e "s/xxxx/with_the_number/" -e "s/xxxxx/with_the/" your_file_new.txt

Comment: I think "/>\d+"/> may help.

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with:

Find what: `"/>[0-9]+"/>`
Replace with: `"/>`